# regexpneed to find word with minus and others

Tags: php, regex

i have for now few types of code that i need to find and replace with regex.

1. {word1/G_KP8zXsDp8/word2}
2. {word1/GKP8zXsDp8/word2}
3. {word1/G-KP8zXsDp8/word2}

my replacement now is: `/({word1\/)(\w+)\/(\w+)/` and it finds 1st and 2nd cases, but don't find 3rd one. and I need it what it would be in `match[2]` `$2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\w` doesn't match a hyphen by default — it is a shorthand representation for the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

To fix this, you can update your regex to include `-` as well. Use `[\w-]+` instead of `\w+`.

```
/({word1\/)([\w-]+)\/(\w+)/
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xI5qS3/1)

Comment: exactly what i was searching! THANK YOU!!